# How to define an ItemTemplate for GridView (inside a ListView) so it can be used in multiple different ListViews?

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, datatemplate

I have some `ListView`'s which bind to collections in the ViewModel. The type of items in those collections are the same (let's call them `TypeA`) which is a class exposing multiple simple type properties. I would like to display them in a `GridView` inside the `ListView`. Naturally, I would want to define a `DataTemplate` for this `TypeA` so that I don't have to duplicate the same XAML for each of the `ListView`'s. All of the examples I've found so far define the `ItemTemplate` inside the `ListView`. How can I make a resource and let different `ListView`'s refer to this single resource?

UPDATE:

I am posting my XAML code for better clarification. My original XAML code (simplified) looks like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MYCOLLECTION}" SelectionMode="Extended" >                                                                       
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Prop1}" >
        <GridViewColumn.Header>
          <Border >
            <TextBlock Text="Prop1" />
          </Border>
        </GridViewColumn.Header>
      </GridViewColumn>
      <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Prop2}" >
        <GridViewColumn.Header>
          <Border >
            <TextBlock Text="Prop2" />
          </Border>
        </GridViewColumn.Header>
      </GridViewColumn>
      <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Prop3}" >
        <GridViewColumn.Header>
          <Border >
            <TextBlock Text="Prop3" />
          </Border>
        </GridViewColumn.Header>
      </GridViewColumn>
...                         
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I have many dependency properties set to the headers and that's why I put individual Header items as well as why my code is really long--hence why I'm seeking to use a datatemplate.

So my idea is that I can show different selections of the same type in the same way in different `GridView`'s (because we want the column headers to display the names of the properties so we use `GridView`).

BTW those are not the only places I am presenting this data type, so I definitely need to specify a Resource key and restrict this to be used only for GridView. And because I want to display in a Grid way, I assume can't define a `DataTemplate` for my type and use it as `ItemTemplate` in a `ListView`.

Comment: pls post your code for better understanding

Comment: @nit That's true. I am posting to the original question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not even have to define a resource key just set the DataType because that will be used as a key internally by WPF. Just make sure your datatemplates are visible from any control where you want to use it, they will be automatically applied. (Just for example you can define them at application level in the resources of App.xaml, but you probably have separate resource dictionaries):

```
<Application x:Class="WpfTest.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:dataModel="clr-namespace:DataModel"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dataModel:GreekGod}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="Gold"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

For your code you need to define templates for each property because you are using it as a grid and you need to set the cell template for each column after removing the DisplaymemberBinding:

```
               <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource prop1Template}">
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <Border >
                            <TextBlock Text="Prop1" />
                        </Border>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>                                                
                </GridViewColumn>
                ...
```

And put the resource in a visible place just as mentioned before like in the Application resources:

```
                <Application.Resources>
                   <DataTemplate x:Key="prop1Template">
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Prop1}" Foreground="Red"/>
                   </DataTemplate>
                </Application.Resources>
```

You can use a ColumnHeaderTemplate and a ColumnContainerStyle like this:

```
     <GridView
           ColumnHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource myHeaderTemplate}"
           ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyle}"
     >
           <GridViewColumn Header="Prop1" CellTemplate="{StaticResource prop1Template}"/>
     ...
```

where the resources are for example:

```
    <Style x:Key="myHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="myHeaderTemplate">
        <DockPanel>
            <CheckBox/>
            <TextBlock FontSize="16" Foreground="DarkBlue">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <Binding/>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I am aware of the general idea of DataTemplate as resource, as using DataType. But I am really looking for some specific example. Because I can't make it work. Please see my update

Comment: Can you be more precise on what does not work. Is your code compiling? can You see your items but the templates are not applied? Are the templates applied only for one control and not the others?

Comment: Please see my update. My code just simply does not compile. And yes, I would like to use this template only for GridView inside a ListView

Comment: The real pain in the ass is the GridViewColumn Header. As I mentioned, my code is a simplified version, in the real version each Header has 4 or 5 more lines with dependency property. So I would like to somehow set the template for those headers (or as I thought, set a template for this specific type specifically for GridView as a whole)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. In my (again simplified) test it works. But in my real app still a bit awkward to apply (or not worth it), since I have some ToolTip, and other property which depend on header name (it might be because of my bad design). So I guess I still have to define one header template for each column header. And I actually only have two or three grid view. So I end up just coping the code anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Just create the `DataTemplate` in the Controls/Windows resources as you would do in the ListViews ItemTemplate and add `x:Key="someKey"` to it.

Now you can refer to it like so:

```
<ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource someKey}"/>
```

Comment: Please see my update to the original post. I just can't make the resource work