# The "Content" property is defined more than once

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uno-platform

I'm trying to create a gridview where I can show all the users in a List and VS is returning me the following error:

> XLS050: The "Content" property is defined more than once

XAML Code:

```
<Page
x:Class="AppTeste.UsersGrid"
Background="{ThemeResource SystemAltMediumHighColor}">
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key ="ImageTextTemplate"/>
</Page.Resources>

<GridView
x:Name="ContentGridView2"
ItemsSource="{x:Bind Users}"
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageTextTemplate}"
IsItemClickEnabled="True"
CanDragItems="True"
AllowDrop="False"
CanReorderItems="False"
SelectionMode="Single"
FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>

    <Grid AutomationProperties.Name = '{x:Bind Name}' Width = '280'>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width = 'Auto'/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width = '*'/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--<Image Source = '' Height = '100' Stretch = 'Fill' VerticalAlignment = 'Top'/>-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Column = '1' Margin = '8,0,0,8'>
            <TextBlock Text = '{x:Bind  Name}' Style = '{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}' Margin = '0,0,0,8'/>
            <StackPanel Orientation = 'Horizontal'>
                <TextBlock Text = '{x:Bind Email}' Style = '{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}'/>
                <TextBlock Text = ' Views ' Style = '{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}'/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation = 'Horizontal'>
                <TextBlock Text = '{x:Bind  ID}' Style = '{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}'/>
                <TextBlock Text = 'ID' Style = '{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}'/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

C# Class:

```
 public sealed partial class UsersGrid : Page
{

    public List<User> Users { get; set; }

    public UsersGrid()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Users.Add(new User() { ID = i, Name = $"Utilizador{i}", Email = $"Utillizador{i}@servidor.pt" });
        }


        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong since I'm using almost unedited GridView template from Microsoft XAML Control Gallery and even if it was fully unedited it would return me the same error.

Comment: Your `<page>` contains 2 elements: a `GridView` and a `<DataTemplate x:Key ="ImageTextTemplate">` . A page can only contain 1 item. Did you mean to put the datatemplate into the Page.Resources ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner to be honest I dont know how to do that

Comment: [SO: how-to-define-an-itemtemplate-for-gridview-inside-a-listview-so-it-can-be-used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891036/how-to-define-an-itemtemplate-for-gridview-inside-a-listview-so-it-can-be-used)   And if you never encountered WPF resources .... time to read up on them and google some tutorials. Theyre hugely useful.

Comment: Move the DataTemplate into the resources block of the page: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Content is set more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919422/content-is-set-more-than-once)

Comment: @richej I've tried that, still returning the same error

Comment: @PatrickArtner No, i've already tried with some different blocks

Comment: Ok, there is still a Grid and a GridView set as content of the page. You need to wrap them into a stackpanel or grid..

Comment: @richej Thanks, finally solved! :) Now I just need to know how to bind the parameters from the List.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `Page` can have only a single element as its content. In this case you have two - the `GridView` and `Grid`.

To fix this, wrap the two inside another layout element like `Grid`. In general, ensure the `Page` has just a single child  .

**Update**: After re-reading the code, it seems you actually want the `Grid` to be the `ItemTemplate` of the `GridView`. In such case it would look as follows (you need to replace `YOURMODELTYPE` with your actual item type):

```
<GridView
x:Name="ContentGridView2"
ItemsSource="{x:Bind Users}"
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageTextTemplate}"
IsItemClickEnabled="True"
CanDragItems="True"
AllowDrop="False"
CanReorderItems="False"
SelectionMode="Single"
FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
   <GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="YOURMODELTYPE">
    <Grid AutomationProperties.Name = '{x:Bind Name}' Width = '280'>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width = 'Auto'/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width = '*'/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--<Image Source = '' Height = '100' Stretch = 'Fill' VerticalAlignment = 'Top'/>-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Column = '1' Margin = '8,0,0,8'>
            <TextBlock Text = '{x:Bind  Name}' Style = '{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}' Margin = '0,0,0,8'/>
            <StackPanel Orientation = 'Horizontal'>
                <TextBlock Text = '{x:Bind Email}' Style = '{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}'/>
                <TextBlock Text = ' Views ' Style = '{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}'/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation = 'Horizontal'>
                <TextBlock Text = '{x:Bind  ID}' Style = '{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}'/>
                <TextBlock Text = 'ID' Style = '{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}'/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>   
   </DataTemplate>
  <GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Comment: I think the problem is mostly coming from the bad indentation in the file: it's not obvious there's 2 elements in the `<Page />`

Comment: Maybe the `Grid` is actually supposed to be the `<GridView.ItemTemplate>` content now that I am reading through it more carefully 